# java how prevent error output from external library

Tags: java

I'm using a library that gives me a lot of error messages and printed stack traces on the console. Is there any way to prevent that output? I only want it to show my own output generated with `System.out`

Comment: What library? What stack traces? What code? What have you tried?

Comment: [I downvoted because the question may appear clear to the poster, but it is not for other readers](http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion). Also too little information is provided.

Comment: You can _technically_ use `System.err.close()` to stop _all_ error messages, but that is a bad idea and most likely you just need to handle your `Exceptions`.  We need more information.

Comment: Please provide the output, and show which are the desireable log lines, and which are the ones you would like be ignored. Also, include information about the library.

Comment: The *library* is actually printing stuff out on the console?  That's generally poor design. As suggested in comments, maybe it's just throwing an exception and you're doing the printing?  If so, that's easy enough to handle.

Comment: Nexevis answer worked

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the System.out PrintStream with a no-op stream, and use the original for your printing (Java 11+):

```
    PrintStream stdout = System.out;
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(OutputStream.nullOutputStream()));
    try {
        System.out.println("printing to System.out");
        stdout.println("printing to stdout");
    } finally {
        System.setOut(stdout);
    }
```

If you're not using Java 11+ you will need to replace `OutputStream.nullOutputStream()` with your own:

```
    OutputStream nullOut = new OutputStream() {
        @Override
        public void write(int b) {}
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch all the exceptions and then do nothing with them. I assume this is for a learning exercise, so go nuts :D

```
try { 
        fancyLibraryStuff(); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //whistles quietly
    }
```